# Modifying the Java Ford Fulkerson implementation to print the maximum flow being used at each edge in the max flow solution?

Tags: java, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

I'd like to modify [this implementation of the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ford-fulkerson-algorithm-for-maximum-flow-problem/) (Also posted below) so that I can graph the nodes and analyze the data. I'd like to not only output the max flow, but also the max flow at each edge for example if the max flow is 50 and it uses a flow from node 1 to 3 with value of 10 I'd like to print it in a format along the lines of 1 - 3 - 10 or something like that. I've tried printing u and v and then the residual[u][v] but it doesn't look right. Any ideas?

```java
// Java program for implementation of Ford Fulkerson algorithm 
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.LinkedList; 

class MaxFlow 
{ 
    static final int V = 6; //Number of vertices in graph 

    /* Returns true if there is a path from source 's' to sink 
    't' in residual graph. Also fills parent[] to store the 
    path */
    boolean bfs(int rGraph[][], int s, int t, int parent[]) 
    { 
        // Create a visited array and mark all vertices as not 
        // visited 
        boolean visited[] = new boolean[V]; 
        for(int i=0; i<V; ++i) 
            visited[i]=false; 

        // Create a queue, enqueue source vertex and mark 
        // source vertex as visited 
        LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
        queue.add(s); 
        visited[s] = true; 
        parent[s]=-1; 

        // Standard BFS Loop 
        while (queue.size()!=0) 
        { 
            int u = queue.poll(); 

            for (int v=0; v<V; v++) 
            { 
                if (visited[v]==false && rGraph[u][v] > 0) 
                { 
                    queue.add(v); 
                    parent[v] = u; 
                    visited[v] = true; 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        // If we reached sink in BFS starting from source, then 
        // return true, else false 
        return (visited[t] == true); 
    } 

    // Returns tne maximum flow from s to t in the given graph 
    int fordFulkerson(int graph[][], int s, int t) 
    { 
        int u, v; 

        // Create a residual graph and fill the residual graph 
        // with given capacities in the original graph as 
        // residual capacities in residual graph 

        // Residual graph where rGraph[i][j] indicates 
        // residual capacity of edge from i to j (if there 
        // is an edge. If rGraph[i][j] is 0, then there is 
        // not) 
        int rGraph[][] = new int[V][V]; 

        for (u = 0; u < V; u++) 
            for (v = 0; v < V; v++) 
                rGraph[u][v] = graph[u][v]; 

        // This array is filled by BFS and to store path 
        int parent[] = new int[V]; 

        int max_flow = 0; // There is no flow initially 

        // Augment the flow while tere is path from source 
        // to sink 
        while (bfs(rGraph, s, t, parent)) 
        { 
            // Find minimum residual capacity of the edhes 
            // along the path filled by BFS. Or we can say 
            // find the maximum flow through the path found. 
            int path_flow = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
            for (v=t; v!=s; v=parent[v]) 
            { 
                u = parent[v]; 
                path_flow = Math.min(path_flow, rGraph[u][v]); 
            } 

            // update residual capacities of the edges and 
            // reverse edges along the path 
            for (v=t; v != s; v=parent[v]) 
            { 
                u = parent[v]; 
                rGraph[u][v] -= path_flow; 
                rGraph[v][u] += path_flow; 
            } 

            // Add path flow to overall flow 
            max_flow += path_flow; 
        } 

        // Return the overall flow 
        return max_flow; 
    } 

    // Driver program to test above functions 
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception 
    { 
        // Let us create a graph shown in the above example 
        int graph[][] =new int[][] { {0, 16, 13, 0, 0, 0}, 
                                    {0, 0, 10, 12, 0, 0}, 
                                    {0, 4, 0, 0, 14, 0}, 
                                    {0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 20}, 
                                    {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 4}, 
                                    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} 
                                }; 
        MaxFlow m = new MaxFlow(); 

        System.out.println("The maximum possible flow is " + 
                        m.fordFulkerson(graph, 0, 5)); 

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you flow along an augmenting path, you increase each edge in `rGraph` with the flow value (and decrease its reverse by the same value). Since `rGraph` is initialized to be the value of `graph`, this means that you can get what you want by taking the positive entries in `graph[u][v] - rGraph[u][v]`. With your example, the result is

```
0 12 11 0 0 0
-12 0 0 12 0 0
-11 0 0 0 11 0
0 -12 0 0 -7 19
0 0 -11 7 0 4
0 0 0 -19 -4 0
```

which matches the result in CLRS Fig. 26.6, p. 727, where this example appears to have its origin.